# Is trait used to describle only mankind?

Tags: idiomatic-language

cambridge gives these explanations about [trait](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trait?q=trait%20)

> a particular characteristic that can produce a particular type of behaviour
>
> a characteristic, esp. of a personality:
>
> A trait is also a characteristic of an organism that is passed from parent to child.

It seems that trait is used to describle only mankind, is my understanding right?

Comment: No. Animals have 'particular types of behaviour' too!

Comment: @KateBunting So, trait is used to describle only animals, right?

Comment: That isn't what I said. _Both_ humans _and_ animals  can show traits.

Comment: @KateBunting What I mean is trait could be used to describle only animals including humans, could not be used to describle things, is my understanding right?

Comment: No, we wouldn't describe an inanimate object as having a trait.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, I cannot see the difference between my "'trait' could not be used to describle inanimate objects" and your comment.

Comment: I meant 'No, it couldn't', not 'No, you are wrong'. I was confirming what you said!!

Comment: Non-living things can have traits too.  E.g. [The salmon pink paper on which the Financial Times is printed is not now its only distinctive trait in the media landscape.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/collegeofjournalism/entries/2b8381ef-93e6-3cce-ab04-1bd8cf1c934c), or [Hostility towards journalists is a universal trait of hardline nationalist movements.](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-41263073)